# Cost function turning into NaN

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a one layer neural network and there's NaN values in cost function(Sigmoid). I've checked it and I found that the reason is that I have logarithm of 0.

```
def compute_cost(y_model,y_train):
    m = y_train.shape[0]  
    cost = - (1 / m) * np.sum(np.multiply(y_train, np.log(y_model)) + np.multiply(1 - y_train, np.log(1 - y_model)))
    return cost
L = compute_cost(y_model,y_train)
```

Can anybody help with this? I have no idea  how to avoid from that error.

Comment: What is the value of `y_model`?

Comment: numbers between 0 and 1. I have 1 there, so that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to add `epsilon << 1` to your expressions in the log. This way, if `y_train == 0`, the expression in the log will be very small, but not NaN.

For example, take `epsilon = 1e-5` and modify your expression this way:

```
def compute_cost(y_model,y_train):
    m = y_train.shape[0]  
    eps = 1e-5
    cost = - (1 / m) * np.sum(np.multiply(y_train, np.log(y_model + eps)) + np.multiply(1 - y_train, np.log(1 - y_model + eps)))
    return cost
L = compute_cost(y_model,y_train)
```

You may get the wanted result this way, without NaN.